# save rdata environment with timestamp

Tags: r

I am trying to loop a code every 24h to download and process data from a database that updates every day. I would like it to save automatically with the date.

This is the line I'm using to save the environment.

```
    save.image("~/Bus data/leeds bus live/timetable data/itm_gtfs/yorkshire.data.RData")
```

How can I modify it so it captures the current date as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can paste() them together. I also prefer myself to set wd a command before having to repeat the path

```
setwd("~/Bus data/leeds bus live/timetable data/itm_gtfs")
   save.image(paste(Sys.date(),"yorkshire.data.RData", sep = "."))
```

Comment: that looks like it should work but I get this error:                                                             
                                                                      
               Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "wb") :
  cannot open compressed file '2021-07-20 10:24:03_yorkshire.data.RDataTmp', probable reason 'Invalid argument'
Warning message:
In file.remove(outfile) :
  cannot remove file '2021-07-20 10:24:03_yorkshire.data.RDataTmp', reason 'Invalid argument'

Comment: I tried to format that comment better but it didn't work, sorry about that

Comment: @MateoBartra I am unsure why that doesnt work.  I am getting the same error

Comment: fixed it using: save.image(paste(Sys.Date(), "yorkshire.data.RData", sep="."))  I think sys.time and sys.date work in slightly different ways